# check number of digits onchange javascript

Tags: html, numbers, digits

Hi i have a number input.
so it works good in explorer because it has no arrows there.
and in chrome and newer browsers it isnt taking care of max length.

```
  <input type="text" id="amount2" name="quantity2" class="amountBox" value="0"  onchange="ChangeSecondAmount(this.value)" maxlength="4" onkeypress="return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(((event||window.event).which||(event||window.event).which)));"/>
```

maybe i can change the onkeypress function to check the amount of digits?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'max' attribute to specify the length.

Comment: but it doesnt help because i want that the user will change that box